# Is it possible to fill a normal array with values from the sql server?

Tags: c#

I want to create a method that returns an array of my class i know how to do with arrayList but i need to fill a 'normal' array[].

I'm doing this with arrayList

```
public ArrayList GetListProductFamily()
{         
    ArrayList arrayProductFamily = new ArrayList();

    IConnection conn = ConnUtil.GetConnection();
    string query = GET_QUERY;

    ProductFamily productFamily = new ProductFamily();

    try
    {
        conn.ExecuteReader(query);

        if (conn.DataReader.Read())
        {
            productFamily.cIdProductFamily = DB.LoadString(conn.DataReader, "CIDPRODUCTFAMILY");
            productFamily.cProductFamily = DB.LoadString(conn.DataReader, "CPRODUCTFAMILY");
            productFamily.lActive = Convert.ToInt32(DB.LoadInt(conn.DataReader, "LACTIVE"));

            arrayProductFamily.Add(productFamily);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error("Error", ex);
    }

    return arrayProductFamily;
}
```

Comment: This code will always return just one record.

Comment: Why are you using `ArrayList`? And why are you adding multiple references to the same object? (You should be creating a new object on each iteration of the loop.) I would recommend using `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList`... you can then call `ToArray` if you really need to, but I wouldn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ProductFamily[] GetListProductFamily()
{
    List<ProductFamily> arrayProductFamily = List<ProductFamily>();

    IConnection conn = ConnUtil.GetConnection();
    string query = GET_QUERY;


    try
    {
        var dataReader = conn.ExecuteReader(query);

        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            ProductFamily productFamily = new ProductFamily();
            productFamily.cIdProductFamily = DB.LoadString(dataReader, "CIDPRODUCTFAMILY");
            productFamily.cProductFamily = DB.LoadString(dataReader, "CPRODUCTFAMILY");
            productFamily.lActive = Convert.ToInt32(DB.LoadInt(dataReader, "LACTIVE"));

            arrayProductFamily.Add(productFamily);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error("Error", ex);
    }

    return arrayProductFamily.ToArray();
}
```

Its pretty simple, just replace `ArrayList` in your class with `List<ProductFamily>` and then return the `.ToArray()` for the list.

The use of `ArrayList` is generally depreciated since the introduction of Generics, and you should avoid it as much as possible over the use of `List<T>` with strong typing.

You were also not iterating through your reader, and I'm not sure what `DB.LoadXXX` does, but I'm assuming it takes a `IDbDataReader` and loads the specified column name. These can be replaced with `dataReader.GetInt32` or `dataReader.GetString`, depending on what you want to read.

It should also be noted that you want to check for `DBNull`, otherwise you will throw an exception early and exit out. You probably want to move the try/catch inside the while loop so that one single record doesn't cause the reader to fail.

You also want to use the reader in a `using` loop, but I'll leave that up to you to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by changing your code following way:

```
//ArrayList arrayProductFamily = new ArrayList();
ProductFamily[] arrayProductFamily = new ProductFamily[1];
```

But this will make you problem because above array is fixed length. You are using `ExecuteReader` so you can not count total number of records. So you need to change the length dynamically. You can do it using `Array.Resize`, your code may be change like following

```
    while (dataReader.Read())
    { 
      Array.Resize(ref arrayProductFamily , arrayProductFamily.Length+1);

.... rest of your code

    }
```